# JAVA mysql INSERT error

Tags: java, mysql

```
 private final static String INSERT = "INSERT INTO electric_usage" +
        "(objId, useTime, name, usage) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";    

    public static boolean insertUsage(int index, Timestamp time, String name, double usage) {
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            con = DBManager.getInstance().getConnection();

            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT);

            java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();


            stmt.setInt(1, index);
            stmt.setTimestamp(2, time);
            stmt.setString(3, name);
            stmt.setDouble(4, usage);
            stmt.addBatch();

            stmt.executeBatch();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            DBManager.getInstance().close();
        }

        return true;


    }
```

make INSERT query like this but this code occur syntax error

other load query is work fine only this INSERT quert occur error

im trying to INSERT query in console it occur same error

my query is wrong?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usage) VALUES (192, '2015-09-10 13:55:57', 'test', 0.0045196452704869055)' at line 1
```

table is

```
objId(int length 8 not null)
useTime(timestamp length 0 not null)
name (varchar length 255 not null)
usage (double length 11 not null)
```

Comment: Did you run same query from DB directly What output you got?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi
 
 
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, time, name, usage) VALUES (192, '2015-09-10 13:42:56', 'test', 0.01345383' at line 1

Comment: My concern is index is the keyword in mysql so it is complaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is a reserved word so you should not use it to name a column. List of reserved words here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 1):

That's because your column names `index/usage` are all  [MySQL Reserve words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) and so needs to be escaped using backtique like below

```
INSERT INTO electric_usage (`index`, `time`, `name`, `usage`)
```

Always avoid using table/column name as reserve word else you will have to suffer likewise. Use proper naming convention like prefix `t_` for table names and `c_` for column names.

Comment: @user2637015, `usage` is also a reserve word. Do proper naming always. see suggestion in answer.

Answer (score 0):

**index is reserved word in mysql you can't use mysql reserved words.when you write query in query browser than reserved words shows in blue. so please take care about this.if you write query in java coding directly you can't find these type of issues.**